# Android audio processing using ffmpeg?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I am develloping my own android media player ,so i opted for ffmpeg for decoding, i've successfully decoded and rendered video but there is no sound now i don't know how to add audio decoding audio to my video decoding and even how to decode a simple audio file and then render it in android using jni.what instruction i have to use (Avframe openinput and then what)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this project at github.

https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg

This project has compiled ffmpeg with x264, lame and other libraries.

I have studied this project, and found that Android AudioTrack class is accessed natively, the decoded audio frames are then fed to instance of AudioTrack.